# Determine the absolute maximum and minimum of $f$ on the interval $I$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Determine the absolute maximum and minimum of $f(x)= 3x^2 + 5x − 2 $ on the interval $I=[−2, 3]$

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150194/discussion-on-question-by-alessandro-terminiello-determine-the-absolute-maximum); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2):

From the plot below, we can see that the maximum value is $f(3) = 40$ and the minimum value is $f(-2) = 0$.

If you don't want to solve that through MATLAB, you can also draw the original quadratic function on $[-2,3]$ and then take the absolute value, so that you can compare the value on end points of interval $[-2,3]$ and the value at extreme value $\frac{-5}{6}$.

For codes and plot of MATLAB, see the screenshots below:

[image]
[image]